# i18next dosen't change language at nextjs app

Tags: localization, next.js, internationalization, i18next, next-i18next

I'm trying to use i18next for localtization, it works well as it translates english text to arabic `{t("title")} ==> مرحبا`.
But when i try to change language to english with
`const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()`
`i18n.changeLanguage('en')`
it dosen't change.
How to fix this.

I got that error at server vscode terimanl `react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at nextjs Docs.
It seems changing locales at nextjs not the same as reactjs, with invoking `i18n.changeLanguage('en')`.
But instead use.

```
<Link href="/fr/another" locale="en">
  <a>To /fr/another</a>
</Link>
```

Will do the job.
more information: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing